# Adjust pie chart slice size by dragging the edge

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to adapt the growing pie demo on Raphaël's website to suit my own needs. http://raphaeljs.com/growing-pie.html

The demo is almost perfect as it is, but I would like the user to be able to drag the edges of the slices to adjust their size, instead of clicking on them. This would be not only more intuitive, but also allow for adjusting the size exactly, instead of the stepped approach in the demo.

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not easy.  You'd need individual "pie slice edge" objects to trap drag events and some trigonometry to calculate the angle of the new slice once it is dropped.  Have fun!

Comment: Is that the smartest way to do it in general, or just because I'm adapting this code? It doesn't have to be the exact code of the Growing Pie demo.

Comment: Drawing the object is easy, deciding on rules and creating the UI to drag the edges of slices to increase their size is the hard part.  I think that this growing pie demo is a great place to start - it's fairly simple and shows how to trap the click event for a slice, you'd need to extend it so that you can trap drag start/mouse down events on edges.

Comment: any luck with this? I'm about to explore accomplishing this on top of d3.js

Comment: I eventually gave up with my pie-in-the-sky dreams, and did an interface that allows users to cycle the slices and grow/reduce them with keyboard controls. If you have any luck with making something more spectacular with d3.js, keep me posted :)

Comment: Basically, the short answer is... the UI would become unstable for older browsers (/ computers) because every mousemove event would trigger a complex (for most PCs) calculation. Though a good algorithm in a succinct answer (herein) might solve the problem -- you'd still have to compensate for the mousemove event running in a client (browser) JavaScript interpreter. V8 is great, but even that engine would be slow for what you ask... though definitely possible (see @James comment).

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching your solution from a different UI perspective. Does the user have to manipulate the PI? Or, can the PI represent the user's response? Ask the user for a percentage, or some other value... then draw the UI interactively. This would eliminate the need to constantly calculate a value for every mousemove event triggered (basically) every pixel the mouse moves.

Comment: Agreed. Dragging around a pie chart is fun, but not particularly useful. Humans are notoriously imprecise, especially when it comes to mouse movements. What kind of data could the chart possibly represent?

Comment: The chart can represent any data. What is important is how to present the user-input in a way that makes sense to them in an immediate yet precise fashion. Not trying to circumvent the question... but, rather, illustrate that the answer is dependent entirely on the response the user expects.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using [GSAP](http://greensock.com/) for this. It has a [Raphaël plugin](http://greensock.com/RaphaelPlugin) and a [Directional Rotation plugin](http://greensock.com/DirectionalRotationPlugin).